# Counting all words from text and ordering it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I did it and it works as intended but it seemed very inefficient. I made the string a list, then I standardize it (removing accents, commas and points). After that, I count every word using a dictionary, then sort it in a loop.

Is there a better way to do it?

Edit - Thanks to you both, with your tips I managed to improve the code a lot, it's much faster and efficient now: https://pastebin.com/EN74daBG

```
import unidecode
from operator import itemgetter


def word_counter(text):
    counter = {}
    for word in text.lower().replace(",", "").replace(".", "").split():
        standardize = unidecode.unidecode(word)
        if standardize.isalnum():
            counter.setdefault(standardize, 0)
            counter[standardize] += 1
    for key, value in sorted(counter.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True):
        print("{} = {}".format(key, value))


word_counter('''text here''')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All in all this is not bad.

## Split into functions

I would split this into more functions.

1. to generate a stream of words
2. to do the count
3. for the presentation

## splitting the text

This is a simple generator

```
def text_split(text):
    text = text.lower().replace(",", "").replace(".", "")
    for word in text.split():
        yield unidecode.unidecode(word)
```

You can generalize this a bit using `re` and `string.punctuation`:

```
import re
import string

PUNCTUATION = re.compile(rf'[{string.punctuation}]')
def text_split_re(text):
    text = PUNCTUATION.sub('', text.lower())
    for word in text.split():
        yield unidecode.unidecode(word)
```

This removes all punctuation in 1 go.

## Counter

you use `dict.setdefault`, so you read the documentation. If you had looked a tiny bit further, in the `collections` module, you'd have found [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), which is exactly what you need, especially with it's `most_common` method. This is so handy, you don't really need the second method. You just need to feed it to the `Counter`.

## presentation

```
def print_result(word_count: Counter):
    for word, count in word_count.most_common():
        print(f'{word} = {count}')
```

as simple as:

## putting it together

```
from collections import Counter         
if __name__ == '__main__':
    words = text_split_re('''text here''')
    word_count = Counter(words)
    print_result(word_count)
```

## tests

splitting this in parts also allows you to unit-test each of the parts

```
assert list(text_split_re('text here')) == ['text', 'here']
assert list(text_split_re('Text here')) == ['text', 'here']
assert list(text_split_re('Text he.re')) == ['text', 'here']
assert list(text_split_re('''Text 
    here''')) == ['text', 'here']
```

Answer (score 3):

You've put your logic into a function which is great for reusability and testing, but you call your function regardless of whether you run the script or you import it: get yourself familiar with the [`if __name__ == '__main__':`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/419163/5069029) guard.

Now for the text processing part: you normalize your text using two different approaches:

- `lower` + `replace` on the whole text
- `unidecode` on single words

Instead, I would suggest doing the whole normalization on a per-word basis. This is twofold:

1. You avoid duplicating the entire text in memory 3 times in a row, only each word;
2. You can improve the function by accepting a stream of words instead of the entire text at once.

You can also improve this normalization process using [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) to [remove all the punctuation at once](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21635971/5069029).

Then you can [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) this function over all words, [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) them and [count](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) them more efficiently:

```
import sys
import unicodedata
from collections import Counter

import unidecode


REMOVE_PUNCTUATION = dict.fromkeys(
    i for i in range(sys.maxunicode)
    if unicodedata.category(chr(i)).startswith('P')
)


def normalize(word):
    return unidecode.unidecode(word.translate(REMOVE_PUNCTUATION)).lower()


def word_counter(words_stream):
    return Counter(filter(str.isalnum, map(normalize, words_stream)))
```

Now you could call you function using whatever stream suits your needs:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    count = word_counter('''text here'''.split())
    print(count)
```

Or, more memory friendly:

```
def read_file_word_by_word(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            yield from line.split()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    count = word_counter(read_file_word_by_word('the_file_name.txt'))
    print(count)
```